# Map through array of objects and add counter of elements with the same property value

Tags: javascript

Given following array:

```js
const arr = [
  {color: 'red'}, 
  {color: 'red'}, 
  {color: 'green'}, 
  {color: 'blue'}, 
  {color: 'blue'}, 
  {color: 'red'}]
```

how to map through its element to create an array of objects extended with property `colorIndex` which would work as a counter of how many previous elements have the same `color` property?

the result would be a following array:

```js
[
  {color: 'red', colorIndex: 0}, 
  {color: 'red', colorIndex: 1}, 
  {color: 'green', colorIndex: 0}, 
  {color: 'blue', colorIndex: 0}, 
  {color: 'blue', colorIndex: 1}, 
  {color: 'red', colorIndex: 2}
]
```

is there some elegant solution to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Edit:

Based on @FZs comment, I'm posting much faster (and more clear) solution. It requires much less operations to complete and much less "brain power" (aka cognitive load) to read it ;)

```js
const arr = [
    { color: 'red' },
    { color: 'red' },
    { color: 'green' },
    { color: 'blue' },
    { color: 'blue' },
    { color: 'red' }
]

var countByColor = new Map();

console.log(
    arr.map(function mapArray(elem, index) {
        var color = elem.color;
        var count = countByColor.get(color) || 0;
        countByColor.set(color, count + 1); // add 1, so next time we spot the color it will get correct counter

        return {
            color, count
        }
    })
)
```

Old vs new perf test: https://jsbench.me/7kkx5zffpm/2

---

## Original answer:

Well, not sure why are you asking and what have you tried already to solve this. It's hard to get proper answer where there is no context at all. But here is my approach, maybe you'll lern a bit of it:

```
arr.map((elem, index) => {

  // we only care about values before current index, to see how many elements with given color were **before**
  var colors = arr.map((obj) => obj.color).splice(0, index + 1);

  return {
    ...elem, // using spread operator to get all properties of original object
    count: colors.reduce(
      (prev, curr) => (curr == elem.color ? prev + 1 : prev),
      -1 // starting from -1 to get 0-based counter
    ),
  };
})
```

See it on stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-bnru4m

Read more about **reduce**:
https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Read more about **spread** operator:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Read more about **splicing** an array:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Read more about **mapping** an array:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Hi @Marcin, thank you very much for you answer. I couldn't quite figure out the logic that would work here - I wanted to attach my attempt but honestly I felt like I put myself in some mindset brackets and unnecessarily pivoted around the solution that could never work. Thanks for you help

Comment: This runs in O(n^2) time, while this task can be accomplished in O(n) time by keeping a Map of counts per color.

Comment: Good point @FZs! I do need to learn more about algorithms, sounds like something you need to keep an eye onto

Comment: @Whichmann - I just updated my answer with much more "elegant" solution

Comment: @FZs how about now? It got som serious performance boost - 37 ops/sec (old) vs 19906 ops/sec (new)! (according to JSBench.me: https://jsbench.me/7kkx5zffpm/2 )

Comment: @MarcinPevik That's good! +1 "*I do need to learn more about algorithms*" - when you learn about them, they may feel like theoretical stuff that never come up in real life, but they do and if you manage to really understand them, it'll give you a new way to look at and write code.

Answer (score 1):

The first solution that comes to my mind isn't elegant but it will do the trick. Best is to work with and extra object.

```
const foundItems = {};

arr.map(item => {
   let foundItem = foundItems[item.color] ? foundItems[item.color]+ 1 : 0;
   foundItems[item.color] = founditem;
   return {
      ...item,
      colorIndex: foundItem,
   }

})
```